# Call stored procedure based on parameter from data in Crystal report

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am trying to achieve the following scenario using crystal report:

- Call stored procedure from SQL server using parameter that is set from data in each row of table in crystal report. See illustration in the figure below:

[image]

- Each stored procedure for each row will be executed based on value that is passed to stored procedure.

I have been trying to call stored procedure using Database expert, and use the field for stored procedure the same as I use the field from Tables.

The problem is the report will always ask the value for the parameters, as this approach will generate parameter fields based on the parameter that is defined in stored procedure. I want the parameter values to be set automatically based on the data in each row.

Please let me know whether it is possible to achieve this scenario using crystal report. For the information, I don't have access to the source code that generate this report. So, I have to do this on report file.

Comment: are you generating one report for one stored procedure?

Comment: No, I am trying to perform some SQL queries based on the input from each row of report. Let's say from the example, I want to query current exchange rate for each currency.